# Pango text gets blurring when GL viewport is changed

Tags: opengl, pango

I am working with a piece of code which was rendering a texture containing text written using Pango, in a particular GL viewport. I have now had to change the viewport, and put the texture at a different z-distance, however, the text has become blurry. I have tried changing the font size, style, etc., but no success.

I am new to Pango, and this is a rather generic question, but any pointers to what could be the reason will be helpful.

Comment: You might want to include a screenshot. The exact look of "blurry" might actually provide a lot of visual information about what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be mipmapping is kicking in because of the larger z-distance? Could you try to apply

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

to the texture you are rendering the text in?

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you. I will accept the answer.